# Is there a way to shorten this JavaScript code? Returning the array after using the .pop() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function removeFromBack(arr) {
  arr.pop();
  return arr;
}

let shoppingList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana',];

console.log(removeFromBack(shoppingList));
```

Is it possible to combine, somehow, line 2 and 3 into a single line?

Comment: `const removeFromBack = a => a.slice(0,-1)`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov not really the same

Comment: `const removeFromBack = a => (a.pop(), a)`

Comment: Code is really as short as it is going to get.

Comment: Short code isn't always a good thing.  Removing repetition from code is good for maintenance, but "short code" for the sake of being short?  Why?

Comment: This is very nice. I knew about arrow functions (learning) but had no idea what the comma operator does - so I learned something new today! Thank you all.

@devlincarnate This question wasn't trying to make the code short for shortness sake but as an opportunity to see what's possible and see if I can learn something new/different to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```js
function removeFromBack(arr) {
  return (arr.pop(),arr);
}

let shoppingList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana',];

console.log(removeFromBack(shoppingList));
```

Though you might be sacrificing readability for those who don't know the `,` operator.

Comment: Code is longer than original ;)

Comment: @epascarello Closest to what I thought of for one line :)

Comment: Thank you. Learned about the comma operator today!

Answer (score 1):

You could slice from the end.

```js
function removeFromBack(array) {
    return array.slice(0, -1);
}

let shoppingList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana',];

console.log(removeFromBack(shoppingList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const removeFromBack = arr => (arr.pop(), arr);

let shoppingList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana',];

console.log(removeFromBack(shoppingList));
```

Comment: Welp, looks like we had the same idea :D

Comment: @Devchris ya, same. But there are multiple ways for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you could do it even shorter:

```js
const removeFromBack = (arr) => (arr.pop(), arr);

let shoppingList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];

console.log(removeFromBack(shoppingList));
```